# ggplot multi-response bar with percentages per group

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

I have survey data and one of the questions is a multi-response question, so participants could select one option, two options, three options etc.
My participants are grouped into two groups of unequal sizes (patient group and control group).

I now want to have a bar chart which shows how many people from each group picked an answer option in percent per group.

I've succeeded in making a bar chart depicting how many people from each group picked a certain answer by transforming my data into long format. But I'm failing to display percentages per group.

This is my code:

````
discrimination_long <- df.discrimination %>%
  gather(option, value, -record_id, -group) %>%
  group_by(option, group) %>%
  summarise(selected = sum(value))

# Rename levels
discrimination_long$option <- factor(discrimination_long$option, labels = c("cultural", "gender-based", "other", "race", "no discrimination"))

# Create plot with 'fill' aesthetic
ggplot(discrimination_long, aes(x = option, y = selected, fill = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_minimal() + scale_fill_manual(values = c("bc" = "#E25C6F", "hc" = "#b388eb"), labels = c("BCS", "HC")) +
  labs(title = "Types of Discrimination Experienced", x = "Types of Discrimination", y = "Number of People") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = NULL))```
````